# How can I have alternating HTML table row classes when using an embedded Ruby iterator?

Tags: ruby, erb, tailwind-css

Below I have part of an `index.html.erb` file with an HTML table and my goal is to have alternating white and gray rows while using a Ruby iterator. I want odd rows to have `<tr class="bg-white">` & even rows to have `<tr class="bg-gray-50">`. I am using TailwindCSS & I have tried the odd & even transform classes for children but I don't think that is the answer. I don't really understand how to articulate it into an if statement. I can't do "if client ID is odd or even: be white or gray" because if a client is deleted I don't want two white or two gray rows on top/beneath one another (say if client ID 26 is deleted and I have 25 & 27 touching now). Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions.

```
      <tbody>
        <% @clients.each do |client| %>
          <tr class="bg-white">
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ">
              <%= client.first_name + " " + client.last_name %>
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
              <%= client.phone_number %>
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own opinion using Tailwind CSS `even` and `odd` variants is a good and clean solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Here is an example of the generated code of your example using Ruby `.erb`

```html
<table class="w-full">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even:bg-gray-100 odd:bg-blue-100">
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">smith</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">555 111-1111</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even:bg-gray-100 odd:bg-blue-100">
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">johns</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">555 222-2222</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even:bg-gray-100 odd:bg-blue-100">
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">davison</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">555- 333-3333</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is an implementation example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/2BNYhQIwfQ

Remember to add `'even', 'odd'` to the variants section.

```json
variants: {
   backgroundColor: ['odd','even'],
},
```

Comment: Ahh thank you victoryoalli!! I was missing the additional code for the variants section in the tailwind config when I was attempting it on my own earlier.

Comment: Going to add something for other Tailwind noobs like me: make sure that when you add the odd & even to the variants section for backgroundColor in your Tailwind config that you put it in the 'extend: {}' section of your variants because if you just put it in variants, it will disable all of the other default backgroundColor variants such as 'responsive', 'dark', 'group-hover', 'focus-within', 'hover', 'focus' and then none of those things will be working. So very important to put any new additions to the config in the 'extends' section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`cycle`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle) view helper for that:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <%= tag.tr(class: cycle("bg-white", "bg-gray-50")) do %>
        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ">
          # ...
        </td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```